# Android ImageView size is not changing in tablets

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout in android which has two image views. I have provided the images for this in the respective drawable folders for different screens. This layout looks fine on phones but on tablets the images looks does not fill the whole available space.

Even if I change the size of the image the image looks the same, no changes are visible. So in tablets the images are somehow scaled down. I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@drawable/background" >

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/player_score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/you"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/com_score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/com"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

 </RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/com_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
         />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/ready"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="50sp"   />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/player_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rock"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/button"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@string/rock"/>
        <View 
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/text"/>
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/paper"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/button"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@string/paper"/>
         <View 
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/text"/>
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/scissors"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/button"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@string/scissors"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What folders are you putting these tablet drawables in, and what devices are you testing on?

Comment: FYI The second (nested) LinearLayout is not necessary. The views are already contained in a vertically oriented LinearLayout, so wrapping them in another one adds nothing.

Comment: @Tanis I have put the images in the ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi folders. I am testing on emulated Nexus7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can either :

- Change `layout_width` to `match_parent` for both `ImagesView`
- Add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` (also to the `ImageView`s)

Comment: The first method worked. But why is the image scaled down when `Layout_width` is `wrap_content`.

Comment: I think that they didn't scale up : `layout_weight` > 0 give additional vertical space, but they needed also horizontal space to expand.

Answer (score 1):

Use 0dp for a `android:layout_height` and remove the weight from the 2nd textview

```
...
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/com_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
         />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/ready"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="50sp"   />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/player_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
...
```

Comment: I have 3 buttons at the bottom. So removing the layout weight is not an option.